# Windows forms. Visible of panel does not work

Tags: c#

I have several panels on windows forms. I added it to List.

```
 panellist = new List<Panel> { };
        panellist.Add(panel_cells);
        panellist.Add(panel_gdg);
        panellist.Add(panel_picking);
        panellist.Add(panel_stock);
```

Where I set visible of panels to 'false' in circle foreach - it work. But when after it I set visible of one of it to 'true' - it doesn't work. Visible is still 'false'. What do I wrong?

```
foreach (Panel p in panellist) { p.Visible = false; };
        this.panel_gdg.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Do `panel_gdg` and `this.panel_gdg` refer to the same instance?

Comment: The code should work. Use the debugger!

Comment: I used debugger. After  this.panel_gdg.Visible = true; debugger show that it is still 'false'

Comment: Use View > (Other Windows) > Document Outline.  Some odds that you'll now see that this panel is *inside* another panel.  If that outer panel is not visible then the inner can't be visible.  Drag it to fix.